# Changing scenes in Minko

Tags: c++, minko

Is there a standard way to change between scenes in Minko? Specifically, I'm imagining each scene as a different level, and when the user completes some task the entire level changes.

I know I could just update all my meshes and whatnot but this feels poor; is there a way I can build a root node for a new scene and then switch the Canvas to using that root node instead (as well as force a rererender, since all the objects will have changed)?

Comment: If you can load one sub-scene, what's keeping your from removing it and adding another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second idea is fine. You can create a separate root `Node` with its own `SceneManager` sharing the `Canvas`. Add your new scene to this `Node`. When you're ready to switch, change the `SceneManager` you use in the `enterFrame` signal to render. This should trigger a re-render, upload textures, calls component `added` signals...

In Minko, there is no global singleton or anything that would prevent from having to completely separate scenes. Each `SceneManager` will reference its own `AssetLibrary`. This way, if you switch scenes and remove references to the previous `SceneManager`, the assets will be released from memory.

Comment: So effectively the hierarchy contains the `Canvas`, a root `Node`, and then multiple level `Node`s + `SceneManager`s attached to those nodes which I can selectively add/remove as children of the root `Node`?

Comment: I'm not sure that'd work because `SceneManager` are expected at the top of the hierarchy. I'd edit the answer to clarify.